# Panic when building Anchor realloc test

Tags: anchor, realloc

Tried to `anchor build` the realloc test from Anchor repo

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/realloc/programs/realloc/src/lib.rs

but getting the following error

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Code not parseable: Error("Invalid attribute")', lang/syn/src/idl/file.rs:360:58
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

currently using `anchor-lang = "0.25.0"`

resolved! forgot to also update anchor-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved, also need to update anchor-cli